# Jest not covering last import statement in a bunch of files

Tags: react-native, jestjs

Im getting uncovered lines on the last import in certain files when I run `jest`. For example,

```
import { StyleSheet, Platform } from "react-native";
import colors from "../../../../theme/color";
import fontStyles from "../../../../shared/fontStyles";
```

The fontStyles will be uncovered. The issue started after upgrading react-native which makes a bunch of native changes plus, a `.flowconfig` file was created and a `.babelrc` file was created replacing the values for babel that we had in package.json with 
in .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too and it possible solution can be by removing this line on **package.json** or **jest.config.json**

```
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
},
```